# jQuery add attr to end of string

Tags: jquery

I want to add the attribute `href` to the end of an url:

This should be pretty easy.  This is what I have, but I think something's wrong.

```
$('.delete-code').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://website.com/admin/home/deleteCode/"+$(this).attr('href'),
        data: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function() {
            $(row).hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

*This works when I hard-code in the href*

Comment: Can you post the complete code for this?

Comment: what output are you getting and what output are you expecting?

Comment: Updated.  It's a simple ajax call.

Comment: i think you need to post html also. $(this).attr('href') seems strange

Comment: Also, active changes like a deletion should always require a POST request.

Comment: You are right!  I don't know why I used GET... However, the problem still remains.

Comment: I'm an idiot...By adding the element's href, I was doubling the url...
I figured out my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work. The problem is the url. Some browsers need to get 200 OK to call the success callback.

Try changing:

```
url: "http://website.com/admin/home/deleteCode/"+$(this).attr('href'),
```

to:

```
url: "http://www.flickr.com/search/?q="+$(this).attr('href'),
```

It should work.

Also you may want to change some little things:

1. The data property is redundant and don't work with pretty urls out of the box.
2. jQuery has a $.get method to make GET requests.
3. closest('tr') rather than parent().parent() will make your code more readable.
4. href is an element attribute, so it can be accessed directly trough DOM

So maybe this can be a better option depending on what you need:

```
$('.delete-code').click(function() {
    var tr= $(this).closest('tr')
    $.get("http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=" + this.href, 
       function(){
          tr.hide()
       })
    return false
})
```

Good luck.

Comment: This wasn't a fix, but this is the best answer, so I'm awarding you!

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing wrong with your code, it's probably just your DOM traversal or the way you're doing your AJAX.

and Julio Protzek is right, unless you're using an error function or want to make a synchronous XMLHttpRequest (a fairly rare case), you could just as easily say

```
$('.delete-code').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.get(
        "http://website.com/admin/home/deleteCode/"+$(this).attr('href'),
        {}, // or { data: $(this).attr('href') }, if you needed to send that
        success: function() {
            $(row).hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and remember, unless .delete-code applies to an `<a class="delete-code">` element, it's a different element you're trying to get the `.attr('href')` from.